# The formula equivalent of EBITDA for personal finance?

Tags: accounting, budget

I am considering the idea of trying to run my household finance more like a business and I am looking for formulas to gauge household financial health. I am running into issues with EBITDA for example, because the household quarterly financial effects of interest, depreciation and amortization don't really have much effect on monthly basis. Is there away to modify the formula to work for a household or a different one to check financial health (like Distributable Cash Flow?).

Answer (score 1):

This should not be taken to be financial advice or guidance. My opinions are my own and do not represent professional advice or consultation on my part or that my employer. Now that we have that clear...

Your idea is a very good one.

I'm not sure about the benefits of a EBITDA for personal financial planning (or for financial analysis, for that matter, but we will that matter to the side). If you have a moderate (>$40,000) income, then taxes should be one the largest, if not the largest chunk of your paycheck out the door.

I personally track my cash flow on a day-by-day basis. That is to say, I break out the actual cash payments (paychecks) that I receive and break them apart into the 14 day increments (paycheck/14). I then take my expenses and do the same. If you organize your expenses into categories, you will receive some meaningful numbers about your daily liquidity (i.e: cash flow before taxes, after taxes, cash flow after house expenses, ect)

This serves two purposes. One, you will understand how much you can actually spend on a day-to-day basis. Second, once you realize your flexibility on a day-to-day basis, it is easy to plan and forecast your expenses.